# Python while loops: return change task

Tags: python, while-loop

I am very new to Python and I am trying to solve a challenge. The task is:
"Vending machine manufacturers wanted to make their machines return as few coins as possible. Write a program that accepts the amount of money that has to return and calculate how many coins it can get." 
The coins are 2.00, 1.00, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.03.

This  is my code:

```
change = float(input())
result = 0

while change > 0:
    while change >= 2:
        change -= 2
        result += 1
    while change >= 1:
        change -= 1
        result += 1
    while change >= 0.5:
        change -= 0.5
        result += 1
    while change >= 0.2:
        change -= 0.2
        result += 1
    while change >= 0.1:
        change -= 0.1
        result += 1
    while change >= 0.05:
        change -= 0.05
        result += 1
    while change >= 0.02:
        change -= 0.02
        result += 1
    while change >= 0.01:
        change -= 0.01
        result += 1
print(result)
```

My input is 2.20 and the printed result is 0 when is supposed to be 2. It looks like it doesn't loop at all. Can anyone explain me why it doesn't loop, I have no idea what I do wrong.

Comment: `while change == 0:` will loop forever if 0 is the input and exit immediately if it's not 0. I'd assume you just want `while change > 0` or even just `if change > 0` since you have the individual loops

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with float arithmetic.When you think is should be 0 it never gets there. So your loop never exists because change is never > 0, it just gets really small. You should set your threshold value (at the outer while loop) to be about 0.01.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me

```
change = float(input())
result = 0


while change >= 2:
    change -= 2
    result += 1
while change >= 1:
    change -= 1
    result += 1
while change >= 0.5:
    change -= 0.5
    result += 1
while change >= 0.2:
    change -= 0.2
    result += 1
while change >= 0.1:
    change -= 0.1
    result += 1
while change >= 0.05:
    change -= 0.05
    result += 1
while change >= 0.02:
    change -= 0.02
    result += 1
while change >= 0.01:
    change -= 0.01
    result += 1
print(result)
```

your first while loop isn't really needed, because it will only complete it one time and makes the computer confused. sadly i don't know why it doesn't work with the extra while loop but it should work(at least for me) like this.